# Present UIAlertController in landscape when the parent view controller is configured for portrait only

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, uialertcontroller, uideviceorientation

In my app, there's a `videoViewController` that's configured for portrait only.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

That is, when the user rotates the device from portrait to landscape, the live preview (which is in the `videoViewController` view's hierarchy) does not rotate with the device (like the Apple Camera app).  When the `videoViewController` to presents the `UIAlertController` while the device in is landscape mode, the instance on the `UIAlertController` is in portrait.  How can I assure the `UIAlertController` is presented in accordance with the device orientation?  Any input is appreciated.

[image]

Also, if I use the `UIAlertView` instead of the `UIAlertController`, the instance of the `UIAlertView` will rotate accordingly.  Because the `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8.0, I don't want to use it.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you may want to try subclassing UIAlertController and overriding supportedInterfaceOrientations

Comment: @GirishNair I have not

Comment: @Daniel unfortunately if you override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and add `landscapeLeft` and `landscapeRight`, the alert appears portrait at first, then when you tilt the screen into landscape it breaks the portrait camera view underneath, allowing it to rotate incorrectly.

I'm guessing Apple is doing it by building a camera view directly onto the window layer, so UIAlertControllers over the top can just position themselves correctly based on interface orientation without messing with the camera view underneath.